# How to call dispatch_block_t block function in button sender?

Tags: objective-c, button

How can I call dispatch_block_t in button sender? Currently the dispatch_block_t is under a HeadView and park under viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind. Sample code as below:-

```
    - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

        if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader){

            ProductMerchant_HeadView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:ProductMerchant_HeadViewID forIndexPath:indexPath];

            WEAKSELF
            headerView.filterClickBlock = ^{ //Click on filter header
                //something here.....
            };
 reusableview = headerView;  
    }
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

    }
    return reusableview;
}


- (void)clickFilterButton:(id)sender {
//HOW CAN I CALL headerView.filterClickBlock = ^{} HERE?
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the button and the header view? Is the button a subview of the header view? Or is there just one button that's outside of the collection view entirely? Or some other arrangement?

Comment: @robmayoff the button is navigation bar button. I would like to trigger the headerview after click on the button,

Comment: Are there multiple header views in the collection view? If so, how do you know which header view's block you want to call? If not, why not just store the block in a property on the collection view controller?

Comment: got 1 headview with multiple block to call.how can i achieve that?

Comment: That doesn't seem to match the code you posted.

Comment: @robmayoff, i just posted code tat affected. There are few more block overthere

Comment: My question is: why is the `filterClickBlock` property on `headerView` and not on the view controller?